# How can I find which integer Primary Keys in my DB are NOT marked as auto-increment?

Tags: t-sql, primary-key, auto-increment

Is there a query I can run that will tell me which of my fields in all of the database tables that are integer primary keys are NOT marked as auto-increment? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
pk_column_name = c.name,
table_name = o.name
FROM sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic 
    ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.syscolumns c 
    ON ic.object_id = c.id AND COL_NAME(ic.object_id, ic.column_id) = c.name
INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects o
    ON o.id = c.id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1 -- the column is part of a primary key
 AND c.status < 128 -- the column is NOT identity enabled
 AND o.xtype = 'U' -- the object is a user table
 AND c.xtype = 56 -- the column type is int
```

I am including columns that are of the type 'int'. If you want to include types like smallint as well, you can look up its xtype by doing a select on the sys.systypes DMV:

```
SELECT name, xtype FROM sys.systypes
```

Here is an alternative way of doing this using information schema views:

```
SELECT 
pk_column_name = c.COLUMN_NAME,
table_name = c.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS k
ON c.TABLE_NAME = k.TABLE_NAME
AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND c.TABLE_CATALOG = k.TABLE_CATALOG
AND c.COLUMN_NAME = k.COLUMN_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS const
ON k.TABLE_NAME = const.TABLE_NAME
AND k.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = const.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
AND k.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = const.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND k.CONSTRAINT_NAME = const.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(c.TABLE_NAME), c.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 0
AND const.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND c.DATA_TYPE = 'int'
```

Hope this helps. Note that this only works for SQL Server 2005 and above.

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking for PK's that are NOT auto-increment, so should I do c.status <= 128?

Comment: Not <=, but < should suffice! I've changed the code for you. I also deleted the extra comma after o.name. Should work now.

Comment: Perfect! It's exactly what I was looking for and it even helped me find an issue with my DB *before* it went live. Thanks.